# Error: Unable to get value of the property 'length:' object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have this error in my `WebBrowser`

> Error: Unable to get value of the property 'length:' object is null or undefined

[image]

even though I have this code:

```
CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Why am I getting this and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you please post all code related to your Webbrowser Component. It might also pay to be sure that the Webbrowser is Item(0).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the Webbrowser componenet dynamically, I suggest that you set `ScriptErrorsSurpressed = True` at that point.

```
Dim wb as New WebBrowser
wb.ScriptErrorsSurpressed = True
'Other declarations...
```

If it is not created dynamically, then I suggest that you go to the control and manually change the setting to `True` in the design view.

If this doesn't work, please refer to my request/comment on your original post.

EDIT 1

This is your code:

```
Dim Browser As New WebBrowser 
TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page") 
Browser.Name = "Web Browser" 
Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 
TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser) 
AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading 
AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done 
int = int + 1 
CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoHome()
CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

This is how I would write it:

```
Dim Browser As New WebBrowser 
Browser.Name = "Web Browser" 
Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 
AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading 
AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done 
TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page") 
TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
int = int + 1 
Browser.GoHome()
Browser.ScriptErrorsSurpressed = True
```

I see no need for `CType()` at all.

Comment: This is my Form1Load code
`Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
        AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
        int = int + 1
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoHome()
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True`

Answer (score -1):

Your getting the error because the javascript file (www-home-vflVATumV.js) on the http://s.ytimg.com server in the yts/bin folder has an error or has found a dynamic error with the LENGTH property of whatever object it is trying to assess.

Comment: I believe that the OP is asking why he is getting the error even though he has `ScriptErrorsSurpessed = True`, not asking what the Javascript problem is.